# JavaScript - Toggle css style on keyDown

Tags: javascript, keydown

Need some help figuring out what's wrong with my second function. JSfiddle here:
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hswg5ou1/)

```
//add an outline on click
function addOutline(){
    box1.classList.toggle('selected');
}
box1.addEventListener('click', addOutline, false);


//change shape on element with class "selected" when "e" is pressed
function changeShape (event) {
    var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
    var key = event.keyCode;
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(key === 69 && arr[i].className === "selected") {
                box1.classList.toggle('circle');
            }   
        }
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", changeShape, false);
```

Basically what i'm trying to do is, when the key "e" is pressed AND if the elements className is equal to "selected" then the div "box" should toggle the circle class (from the css).

I got it to work with only the keyDown, but when trying to add the className statement to the function, it wont work. Check the jsfiddle at the top to make more sense of this. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to test the class in the `if` statement? `arr` can only contain elements with that class, since that's how you selected them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because className contains multiple classes, this does not work:

```
arr[i].className === "selected"
```

Since `arr` at that point contains *only* elements that include the "selected" class, you don't need that check.

However, if you need it for a different reason, you can use [**`classList.contains`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) instead:

```
arr[i].classList.contains("selected")
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bueLxtf2/)

Comment: Nice catch! I didn't realize the check was useless.

Answer (score 0):

Does your elements have more than one class? If yes, maybe this helps:

```
if(key === 69 && arr[i].className.indexOf("selected") > -1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing this line with `indexOf()` works:

```
if(key === 69 && arr[i].className.indexOf("selected")>-1)
```

### Updated JS Fiddle

That's because the className is not equal to `selected`, but to `selected box center green size200`.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the function for has class that way you don't have to worry about if you have a class that contains selected and then just add the combination of the key code and hasclass().

Here's the function for hasClass and how you can modify your code:

```
function hasClass(el, cls) {
  return el.className && new RegExp("(\\s|^)" + cls + "(\\s|$)").test(el.className);
}
```

Then just change your code to be:

```
if(key === 69 && hasClass(arr[i],"selected")) {
                box1.classList.toggle('circle');
            }
```

Here is the updated fiddle [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hswg5ou1/2/)

Comment: Good point about the possibility of a "...selected..." class.  However, since OP is already using `classList`, the `classList.contains` method should do the work of `hasClass`.